# Как узнать какой шрифт из css не используется на сайте?

Tags: html, css, ide, google-fonts

Достался в распоряжение старый сайт, на нем подключено 14 шрифтов. По таблице загрузок видно, что такое кол-во подргружаемых шрифтов, влияет на загрузку страницы. Хочу почистить лишние, но не знаю как определить какой из шрифтов не используется.

Подскажите, есть какой-то софт или такая возможность в IDE?

Comment: Можно воспользоваться сервисом https://capyba.ru/services/fontfinder/ - прогнать через него страницы сайта. Он определяет все используемые на странице шрифты. Так можно

Answer (score 2):

Итак, если известны названия шрифтов, то надо посмотреть как они должны записываться в `css`. Затем обычным поиском ищем есть ли они в `css-файлах`. Если не используются - удаляем.
Но это еще не все, возможно шрифты записаны в `css`, но описанные селекторы нигде не используются на сайте. Это можно проверить с помощью утилит, например https://github.com/peterbe/mincss, или специальных сайтов, например https://unused-css.com/.

Есть еще вариант полазить по сайту и на глаз определить сколько всего шрифтов используется. Выделить основные, а остальные снести не глядя :)